# Error signing a soap request. Integrity lost

Tags: java, web-services, sign, referential-integrity

I have generated my class with xjc and wsimport tools. I have an Object with all the attributes and elements I need. I have a SignatureType Object that must contain the sign of the data i will send.

My root object looks like this:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "MensajePesadoFirmadoTipo")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "MensajePesadoFirmadoTipo", propOrder = {
    "signature"
})
public class MensajePesadoFirmadoTipo
    extends MensajePesadoTipo
{

 @XmlElement(name = "Signature", namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#", required = true)
    protected SignatureType signature;

...
```

The process I'm doing is: Fill all the information of MensajePesadoFirmadoTipo except SignatureType. Next, I unmarshall to xml and I use Java XMl Signature API. Then I marshall again and I call the WS.

I have an integrity problem of sign because the signed XML It is not the same when I marshall before call the WS.

**XML Signed (signed ok):**

```
<ns1:MensajePesadoFirmadoTipo xmlns:ns1="urn:correos.es:ape.sne.datos.1.0" xmlns:ns2="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" modalidad="1" ns1:idRef="idRef" ns1:idUnico="idUnico" tipo="NOTIFICACION">
...
<ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
...
</ds:Signature></ns1:MensajePesadoFirmadoTipo>
```

**RESULTING XML AFTER MARSHAL (integrity problem, de XML has change):**

```
<ns1:MensajePesadoFirmadoTipo xmlns:ns1="urn:correos.es:ape.sne.datos.1.0" xmlns:ns2="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" modalidad="1" ns1:idRef="idRef" tipo="NOTIFICACION" ns1:idUnico="idUnico">
...
<ns2:Signature>
...
</ns2:Signature>
</ns1:MensajePesadoFirmadoTipo>
```

How can I make this process ok?? Please help!!!

Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: but, what is the problem? in both cases you have the namespaces ds and ns2 defined, so if you (or your platform) use an standar xml parser you'll have no issues

Comment: The signed xml and the final xml are not the same so the server throw me an error of digital signature.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't put the details of your signature (the complete ds:Signature nodes). This would help.

Depending on whether you are using XML Canonicalization transforms or not your signature may be valid even if the XML after marshal is not the same as before. XML canonicalization (google it if not familiar with it) is a mean used to "canonicalize" an XML input before computing the signature. For example, this includes ordering the attribute so that after the canonicalization, MensajePesadoFirmadoTipo in your both snippets will give the same input to the signature computation.

Hope this helps.
Moez